# Iterating trough 3Darray and adding new value to it

Tags: python, list, containers

I want to add the container ID to the 3D array in ship[4] at the position (i,j,k)

```
def addContainerOnShip(ship,container):
    place = findPlace(ship,container)
    if place == False:
        return False
    ship[3].append(container)
    id = getIdContainer(container)
    deck = place[0][0]
    row = place[0][1]
    position1 = place[0][2]
    if len(place) == 2:
        position2 = place[1][2]
        ship[4][deck][row][position1] = id
        ship[4][deck][row][position2] = id
    elif len(place) == 1:
        ship[4][deck][row][position1] = id
    else: 
        return False
    return True

def findPlace(ship, container): #rowsene øker ikke. 
    for i in range(getHeightShip(ship)-1):
        deck = ship[4][i]
        if getLengthContainer(container) == 20:
            for j in range(getWidthShip(ship)):
                row = deck[j]
                for k in range(getLengthShip(ship)-1):
                    position = row[k]
                    if position == 0 and isContainerBelow(ship, [i, j, k]): 
                       return [[i, j, k]] #doble lister fordi den kjører på to elementer
                    k+=1
        elif getLengthContainer(container) == 40:
            for j in range(getWidthShip(ship)):
                row = deck[j]
                for k in range(getLengthShip(ship)-2):
                    position1 = row[k]
                    position2 = row[k+1]
                    if (position1 == 0 and position2 == 0 and isContainerBelow(ship, [i,j,k]) and isContainerBelow(ship, [i,j,k+1])):
                        return [[i, j, k],[i, j, k+1]]
                    k+=1
        else:
            return False  


def isContainerBelow(ship, position):
    deck = position[0]
    row = position[1]
    place = position[2]
    positionBelow = ship[4][deck-1][row][place]
    if deck == 0:
        return True
    elif positionBelow == 0: #there is nothing under here 
        return False
    else: 
        return True
```

I have tried;

```
randomContainers(containers) #randomly generates 10 containers
skip1 = NewShip(6,5,4)
makeDeck(skip1)
con = NewContainer(1111,40,3)
sortContainersWeight(containers)
for el in containers:
    print(el)
    print(addContainerOnShip(skip1,el))
    print(findPlace(skip1,con))
 

print(skip1[4])
```

And this is what i get:

```
[307813, 20, 2, 0, 2]
True
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2]]
[3779799, 20, 2, 2, 4]
True
[[0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3]]
[9725995, 20, 2, 6, 8]
True
[[0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 4]]
[7275339, 40, 4, 6, 10]
True
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
[4210939, 40, 4, 8, 12]
True
[[1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 3]]
[2058645, 40, 4, 11, 15]
True
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
[4558888, 20, 2, 13, 15]
True
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
[9093612, 40, 4, 16, 20]
True
[[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3]]
[2733982, 20, 2, 19, 21]
True
[[1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4]]
[6156045, 20, 2, 22, 24]
True
[[1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1]]
[[[307813, 3779799, 9725995, 7275339, 7275339], [307813, 3779799, 9725995, 7275339, 7275339], [307813, 3779799, 9725995, 7275339, 7275339], [307813, 3779799, 9725995, 7275339, 7275339], [307813, 3779799, 9725995, 7275339, 7275339], [307813, 3779799, 9725995, 7275339, 7275339]], [[4210939, 4210939, 2058645, 2058645, 4558888], [9093612, 9093612, 2733982, 6156045, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

As you cab see it repeats itself.